# Unable to use command genstrings in OS X El Capitan

Tags: ios, xcode, genstrings, osx-elcapitan

I am working on an iOS app using Xcode 6.4 in OS X 10.11 El Capitan (Beta 3).

Whenever I try to localise using the terminal command `genstrings` I get the message

> genstrings: error: unable to find utility "genstrings", not a developer tool or in PATH

I have been getting this error since the 2nd beta.

Did anyone have to deal with this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Print the `$PATH` variable in your terminal, and then go check in those directories for the `genstrings` utility. If you can't find it there, then you need to install it manually or add a directory to your path so it can find the command.

Comment: Thank you @ndmeiri for your answer. The thing is that `genstrings` dos appear in one of the directories... That is the weird thing

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem with El Capitan's release version :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi I am also running into this problem when trying to use Xcode 6.4's `genstrings` in OS X El Capitan, with Xcode 7 installed.

For some reason, the `genstrings` for Xcode 6.4 in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` is missing. I tried to re-install Xcode Developer Tools by running `xcode-select --install` but to no avail.

The solution I am using is kind of a hack which is making a symlink from the `genstrings` in Xcode 7 into Xcode 6.4's `Developer/usr/bin` path as shown in the following command.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/genstrings /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thank you @Nicholas for your help!. It seems to work. I guess this is a temporary fix

Comment: I only have Xcode 6.4 installed and have this exact same problem. The weird thing is that I do have the executable `/usr/bin/genstrings` on my machine, but when I run that I get this same error. Would my only fix at the moment be to install Xcode 7 in parallel and point to that genstrings? This is so strange... :-(

Comment: I installed Xcode 7 as `Xcode.app` after renaming my 6.4 version to `Xcode 6.4.app`. Now genstrings works again, but now my cocoapods doesn't. Is the solution for all this to somehow switch back to the 6.4 command line tools (there is a commend for that I think) and then make that symbolic link like Nicholas is saying?

Comment: Okay, that's it - just have to switch the version of the command line tools in the Xcode settings. So solution for me is: (1) Have both 6.4 and 7 installed, (2) Choose 6.4 version of command line tools in preferences when needing to run cocoapods, (3) Choose 7 version of command line tools in preferences when needing to run genstrings. Of course, that symlink is a brilliant hack as well.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apple is not providing a long term solution

> OS X El Capitan no longer ships with genstrings. That utility is instead provided by Xcode 7. This means that older versions of Xcode won’t find genstrings in /usr/bin like they would on older versions of OS X. (19708961)

[Xcode 7 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

For me, I needed to change the path to my active developer directory.

You can see your current active developer directory by running the following:

```
$ xcode-select -p
```

Which originally output `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

### Solution:

I had to run

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
```

which then changed the output of the first command to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`. After that, the `genstrings` command was found correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) doesn't include `genstrings` any more (see the [Xcode 7 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW1)).  It is now included in Xcode 7. If you have Xcode 6.4 selected as the command line tools, you won't be able to run `genstrings`. You can, however, use `xcrun` and set the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable to run it from Xcode 7, even if that version isn't selected as the command line tools:

```
DEVELOPER_DIR=<path to Xcode 7.x> xcrun genstrings
```

e.g., if you have the latest version of Xcode installed as `/Applications/Xcode.app`, you can do

```
DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app xcrun genstrings
```